# Generate permutations based on provided template. Any better idea than this, to do the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

What do you think about code below? Any better idea, to do the same? Input should be some numbers and char "x", example: 12xx00.

```
from itertools import product

signs = input("signs: ")
template = signs.replace('x', '{}')
wildcard_count = signs.count('x')

results = [
    list(template.format(*digits))
    for digits in product(*(
        range(10)
        for _ in range(wildcard_count)
    ))
]

print(results)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you mean by "better"? For example, does this code run too slowly or use too much memory space? What sort of context are you using it in? If you're looking for overall critiques, you might prefer to ask on [codereview.se] instead, but take [their tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) first and read [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code a lot using a generator expression and coding directly the wildcard replacement value:

```
from itertools import product 

signs = '12xx00'

out = list(product(*('0123456789' if c == 'x' else c for c in signs)))
```

Output:

```
[('1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '1', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '2', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '3', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '4', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '5', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '6', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '7', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '8', '0', '0'),
 ('1', '2', '0', '9', '0', '0'),
 ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, code is really short. Can you please do it without one line loop, or this is impossible? This is first time, when I see that method, and it's hard to imagine for me, how it could look without one line loop. Btw thanks for help!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*without one line loop*", what is the issue with the current solution?